# Sybase SQL - Truncation error occurred. Command has been aborted and find CACHE QUALITY

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase

Need help with below code, as it fails with truncation error

Truncation error occurred.
Command has been aborted.

```
create table monCacheQuality (
        ServerName sysname
        ,CollectionDateTime smalldatetime not null
        ,PhysicalWrites decimal(15, 0) not null
        ,PhysicalReads decimal(15, 0) not null
        ,LogicalReads decimal(15, 0) not null
        ,CacheQuality decimal(15, 0) not null
        ,CacheHitPct decimal(15,4) not null
        )

-- Main code starts here 
declare @physical_read1 decimal(15, 0)
    ,@logical_read1 decimal(15, 0)
    ,@physical_write1 decimal(15, 0)
    ,@cache_search1 decimal (15,4)

declare @physical_read2 decimal(15, 0)
    ,@logical_read2 decimal(15, 0)
    ,@physical_write2 decimal(15, 0)
    ,@cache_search2 decimal (15,4)

while (1=1)
begin
    select @physical_write1 = PhysicalWrites
        ,@physical_read1 = PhysicalReads
        ,@logical_read1 = LogicalReads
        ,@cache_search1 = CacheSearches
    from master..monDataCache

    waitfor delay '00:00:20' -- Log every 20 sec

    select @physical_write2 = PhysicalWrites
        ,@physical_read2 = PhysicalReads
        ,@logical_read2 = LogicalReads
        ,@cache_search2 = CacheSearches
    from master..monDataCache

    insert monCacheQuality
    select @@servername as ServerName
        ,getUTCdate()
        ,@physical_write2 - @physical_write1
        ,@physical_read2 - @physical_read1
        ,@logical_read2 - @logical_read1
        ,case 
            when @physical_read2 - @physical_read1 = 0
                then - 1
            else (@logical_read2 - @logical_read1) / (@physical_read2 - @physical_read1)
            end as CacheQuality
        ,100-(((@physical_read2-@physical_read1)/(@cache_search2-@cache_search1))*100) as CacheHitPct
end
```

Comment: Probably the cacheQuality or CacheHitPct is being truncated. I suspect CacheHitPct, but cant get it to work.

Comment: What's the table definition for `monCacheQuality`?

Comment: Updated my SQL with create table.

Comment: And idea or help to the right resource is highly appreciated

Comment: quick question: col CollectionDateTime is smalldatetime, while function getUTCdate() returns datetime (at least in MS SQL). Do you have an implicit convert there (not familiar with Sybase)?  PS: can you add also the schema for master..monDataCache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if any one wants to set up for CACHE QUALITY for Sybase ASE 15 and up, below script will help:

Changes for the script to work fast without overhead of querying MDA tables and the truncation issue is resolved by switching to `int` datatype.:

- The where clause now makes the script work when Sybase ASE is under heavy loads.
  where `CacheID = 0`
- The last change is just a logic change for when physical reads = 0, this way we save the logical reads. `then @logical_read2 - @logical_read1`

  ```
      -- CREATE A TABLE FOR DURATION SIMULATION
      if not exists(select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'TimeControl')
      begin
        create table TimeControl (counter int)
      end
      go

      -- CREATE TABLE FOR SQL PIPE RESULTS
      if not exists(select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'monCacheQuality')
      begin
        create table monCacheQuality (
        ServerName sysname
        ,CollectionDateTime smalldatetime not null
        ,PhysicalWrites decimal(15, 0) not null
        ,PhysicalReads decimal(15, 0) not null
        ,LogicalReads decimal(15, 0) not null
        ,CacheQuality decimal(15, 0) not null
        )
      end
      go
      create table cache_Begin (
    CacheID int not null,
    InstanceID tinyint not null,
    RelaxedReplacement int not null,
    BufferPools int not null,
    CacheSearches int not null,
    PhysicalReads int not null,
    LogicalReads int not null,
    PhysicalWrites int not null,
    Stalls int not null,
    CachePartitions smallint not null,
    CacheName varchar(30) null
  )
  go
  create table cache_End (
    CacheID int not null,
    InstanceID tinyint not null,
    RelaxedReplacement int not null,
    BufferPools int not null,
    CacheSearches int not null,
    PhysicalReads int not null,
    LogicalReads int not null,
    PhysicalWrites int not null,
    Stalls int not null,
    CachePartitions smallint not null,
    CacheName varchar(30) null
  )
  go

  use tempdb --- change this to be other than the db being monitored !!
  go

  declare @physical_read1 int
        ,@logical_read1 int
        ,@physical_write1 int
  declare @physical_read2 int
        ,@logical_read2 int
        ,@physical_write2 int

  while (select counter from TimeControl) =1 
  begin
        select @physical_write1 = PhysicalWrites
              ,@physical_read1 = PhysicalReads
              ,@logical_read1 = LogicalReads
        from master..monDataCache
        where CacheID = 0

        waitfor delay '00:01:00'

        select @physical_write2 = PhysicalWrites
              ,@physical_read2 = PhysicalReads
              ,@logical_read2 = LogicalReads
        from master..monDataCache
        where CacheID = 0

        insert monCacheQuality
        select @@servername as ServerName
              ,getUTCdate()
              ,@physical_write2 - @physical_write1
              ,@physical_read2 - @physical_read1
              ,@logical_read2 - @logical_read1
              ,case 
                    when @physical_read2 - @physical_read1 = 0
                          then @logical_read2 - @logical_read1
                    else (@logical_read2 - @logical_read1) / (@physical_read2 - @physical_read1)
                    end as CacheQuality
  end


  -- Report the data that is collected.........
  select *
  from monCacheQuality








  ---- reset it back ... (in another Query window)
  update TimeControl 
  set counter = 0 
  go




  --- cleanup ... start and end cache table for next reuse 
  drop table cache_Begin
  go




  drop table cache_End
  go
  ```